# Why is tf.Variable uppercase but tf.constant lowercase?

Tags: tensorflow

There is a little hard to guess why the case  (I mean, upper case versus lower case) of constructors for variable, placeholder and constant is not the same, as below: `tf.Variable()`, `tf.placeholder()`, `tf.constant()`.

What is the inherent difference between the variable method and the rest, that is start with an upper case letter?

Comment: Someone downvoted this without comment, so I upvoted it with this comment. I would also like to know whether there is a reason for this or if it's just different people doing different modules within tensorflow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/constant_op/constant_value_tensors#constant) and [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders) are nodes in the graph (ops or operations). On the other hand [`tf.Variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) is a class.

And in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) python style guide:

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Comment: And here's the link that covers it a little more broadly. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf